# How to insert import statement into AST with Babel.js?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree

I was trying to insert a ImportDeclaration into a snippets of JavaScript code with Babel.js:

```js
const babel = require('babel-core')
const t = babel.types
const traverse = babel.traverse
const template = babel.template
const generate = require('babel-generator').default

const babylon = require('babylon')

const code = [
  "import A from 'a'",
  "import B from 'b'",
  "export default {",
  "  components: {",
  "  },",
  "  methods: {",
  "    init () {",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "}"
].join("\n")
console.log(code)
const ast = babylon.parse(code, {
  sourceType: 'module'
})
var n = []
traverse(ast, {
  ImportDeclaration: {
    exit(path) {
      n.push(path)
    }
  }
})

const name = 'UserDialog',
  src = './user-dialog.vue'
if (n.length) {
  const importCode = "import " + name + " from '" + src + "'"
  console.log(importCode)
  const importAst = template(importCode, {
    sourceType: 'module'
  })()
  // append to last import statement
  n[n.length - 1].insertAfter(importAst);
  console.log(generate(ast).code)
}
```

But I got the following error

[image]

What's the proper way to do this?

FYI:
You can get above code from `git clone https://github.com/aztack/babel-test.git`

Comment: I also tried to `path.insertAfter(importAst)` in `exit` method. But It will cause the `traverse` go into an infinite loop, since I just inserted a `ImportDeclaration`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You'd be best off writing this as a Babel plugin, e.g.

```
const babel = require('babel-core');

const code = [
  "import A from 'a'",
  "import B from 'b'",
  "export default {",
  "  components: {",
  "  },",
  "  methods: {",
  "    init () {",
  "    }",
  "  }",
  "}"
].join("\n");

const result = babel.transform(code, {
  plugins: [myImportInjector]
});

console.log(result.code);


function myImportInjector({ types, template }) {
  const myImport = template(`import UserDialog from "./user-dialog";`, {sourceType: "module"});

  return {
    visitor: {
      Program(path, state) {
        const lastImport = path.get("body").filter(p => p.isImportDeclaration()).pop();

        if (lastImport) lastImport.insertAfter(myImport());
      },
    },
  };
}
```

Comment: Hi, How would you approach a file that doesn't have initial imports (e.g it's the only import on the file?) got stuck on that, and it's not an issue till there are important comments at the beginning of the file like  // eslint-disable

Comment: You can add it to the very top with path.node.body.unshift(myImport()), but this might break if the file has shebangs (#!/usr/...)